# How to create a dialog box that appears without any event triggered in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and I want to create a dialog box, with only one button, informing the user that their time is up in my game. The point is that, as long as I can see dialogs in jQuery appear after certain eventType. For example, after a button is clicked the dialog can appear. But in my situation I don't have any event, it must just appear automatically when the condition in the if statement is true. And when the user clicks OK button on the widget, he/she should be transferred to the page referred below. Any idea how to achieve it?

```
function showTimer() {
    if (timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) == "59" && timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2) == "59") {
        // dialog goes here...
        $.mobile.navigate("#finalPage");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all possible using jQuery:

```
//Initialise the dialog first
var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $.mobile.navigate("#finalPage"); // Your custom code for navigation on button click
        }
    }
});
setTimeout(function(){ // When your condition is met, just call the dialog using this code
    dialog.dialog('open');
},2000);
```

Here,I have used timeout just to show how you can open the dialog at any stage without triggering any click.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/175/

Comment: I get an error message saying: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog', regarding the part where you initialize the dialog.

Comment: It works fine in fiddle. Are you sure you included jquery ui files in your code?

Comment: I have included jquery 1.9.1, and jquery mobile 1.3.1, do i need any other file?

Comment: I guess yes. Check whether you have jquery.ui.js and jquery.ui.css files. You can check the external resources option in jsfiddle I mentioned.

Comment: Well I checked and I hadn't included those two. I included the .js file now, but still I get the same error. Is there any specific place where in my index.html to include it? I mean before or after some other scripts?

Comment: Order of jquery files is important. First include jquery main file ,then your jquery mobile and then jquery ui file. Hope it solves your issue, if issue still remains then try switching the order of jquery mobile and jquery ui file.

Comment: Adding it just under the main jquery (in my case jquery 1.9.1) solved the above error, but now a new error appeared: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for what you are trying? I can probably look into your code then try to find the problem.

Comment: There seems to be some conflict between jquery 1.9.1, and the one on the fiddle. I will try some others. But thanks for this good answer. I see it works find on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

start a timer with setInterval, and check the condition every x milliseconds